# How to use CSS counters in lists with and without resetting the counters?

Tags: css, counter

[Previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469689/how-to-use-css-counters-in-lists-without-resetting-the-counters)

[Paul Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196379/paul-hoffman) asked this question some years ago.

> I want to have multiple "ol" lists where the counter value does not
> reset between lists. Another way to say this is that I want the
> counter for the first "li" in the second list to be one higher than
> the counter value from the last element of the previous list. Is there
> some CSS magic that will do this?

I understand the suggested solution. However, if I now want to add a third list of which the counter has to start with the value one again. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your lists in a higher level wrapper

```css
.list-wrapper {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
  </ol>
  <p> Something else </p>
  
  <ol>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<p> And a different list: </p>

<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
  </ol>
  <p> Something else </p>
  
  <ol>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
    <li> An item</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked as a charm. I've learned something new today! Thank you.

Comment: I've noticed that the Font Awsome lists (fa-ul) I use now have additional numbering (just like regular lists) before the list items after implementing the aforementioned solution, as shown in the image: <https://flic.kr/p/2nV2fi9>. I've don't understand for what reason these lists are now a combination of a Font Awesome and 'normal' ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469691/378779):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #list-one { 
        counter-reset : item;
    }
    #list-three { 
        counter-reset : item 0;
    }
    li {
        display : block;
    }
    li:before {
        display : inline-block;
        content : counter(item) ". ";
        counter-increment : item;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol id="list-one">
        <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="list-two">
        <li>Four</li><li>Five</li><li>Six</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="list-three">
        <li>Seven</li><li>Eight</li><li>Nine</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```